# Creating an R loop for simulated trials of an experiment

Tags: r

I have an experiment with outcomes that are equally as likely. The sample size is 68 billion -- 4^18. I am trying to create a loop that for x trials generates a list of x elements that are random numbers from 1 to 4^18. I want to make it so the function has a operator that lets me choose the sample size. Here is what I have.

```
N = 4^18;N

trialsample <- function(x){
  Trials <- list()
  for(i in 1:x) {
    Trials[[i]] <- round(runif(1, 1, N))
  }
}  

test <- trialsample(5)
test
NULL
```

Comment: You didn't actually seem to ask a question here. Were you expecting your function to return something? Because your function ends with a `for` loop which doesn't return anything. If you wanted the list of trials to be returns, add `Trials` to the end of your function so that value is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, didnt catch that.